# Array Strings (strings[ ] ) is printed out on the same line

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have created an ArrayList that is populated with text from a text file. The String `questions[]`is collecting the different values from the mentioned text file, which are stored in `questions[0]`and `questions[1]`.

*Q1* I want the String arrays to be printed out in different lines. I am using the usual line separator `/n`, to no effect. How do I do this?

*Q2* Each of the Strings has this format "[text" when they are printed out. What can I do to remove the unwanted character?

The text in the file has this format:

`Vad heter äventyrets hjälte?/Frodo`.

**Part of the Client class:**

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            write = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            //Skriva till klienten.
            List<String> questionsList = new ArrayList<>();

            try (Stream<String> questionsStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(quizFile))) {  //Reading from text file
                questionsList = questionsStream
                        .parallel()
                        .collect(Collectors.toList();
                Collections.shuffle(questionsList);                    //Randomizing the Strings.

                while (true) {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(String.valueOf(questionsList));
                    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                        questions = scanner.nextLine().split("/");               //Splitting the textfile.

                        write.println(questions[0] + "\n");                           //Printing out [0]."\n" does not seperate the String to seperate lines.
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(4000);                                 //"Sleeping" between the lines.
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the point of going through a Scanner to iterate on the Strings stored in a list. Just use a loop instead of transforming the list into a STring, and parsing the string with a scanner.. You're not printing anything in that code. Only sending strings to a connection's output stream. Not that you should use a Writer to write text, not a Stream.

Comment: `println()` already has line breaks.

Comment: @JBNizet, can you please exemplify in an answer?

Comment: `for (String question: questionList) { ... }`.